# Jquery check width of CSS if statement

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an Jquery if statement. It should, change the width of an css class if the div that is targeted (.item) is at a width of 50%, for some reason my code is not getting the result I want the element stays at 100%.

```
$(".item").each(function () {
  if ($(this).css({'width': '50%'})) {
      $('.colour').css({'width': '47%!important'});
  }
});
```

Maybe some syntax issue?

Comment: It is a syntax issue indeed, you should use a comma between 'width' & '47%', not a colon.

Comment: @Goombah - incorrect, they're using `{...}`, so it is the correct format

Comment: @Goombah the syntaxis is ok. the use of  `{ prop: value}` is ok

Comment: @Sole Please share the entire code. The code works fine, so, the problem is in `html` or in the assigned `width` of `.item` **-css-**

Comment: @freefaller Nop, the missing space in `!important`is **not** an issue.

Comment: @freefaller No problem! Thx for help!

Comment: Could you explain what actual _problem_ you are trying to solve here in the first place? Perhaps there might be a different solution for this.

Comment: If the div class.item has a width of 50%, I want the .colour width to be set to 47%.

Comment: @Sole... see my updated answer... `.css` doesn't support `!important`

Comment: @Roy, turns out the `!important` **is** an issue!

Comment: @freefaller Oh, you are right about `!important`, so sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you're **setting** the width, and the `if` is checking the return jQuery object...

```
if ($(this).css({'width': '50%'}))
```

You should be returning the width of the object using something like `.width()` or `.outerWidth()`... however, the issue **then** is that it will be in pixels, and not a percentage..

To get around that, you could get the width of the parent element and compare the value... however, that is not an exact science, as there are a large number of things that could effect the values (margin, padding, border, float, etc)...

```
// 0.5 == 50%
if ($(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() == 0.5)
```

```js
$(function() {
  // Timeout to show it happening
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".inner").each(function() {
      // 0.5 == 50%
      if ($(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() == 0.5) {
        // Setting 25% to show big difference
        $(this).css({"width": "25%"});
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div { height: 100px }
.outer { background-color: red }
.inner { background-color: blue; width:50% }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Wait a second...<br/>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

The final issue is that I've just discovered that jQuery doesn't support `!important` as part of the [`.css`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method...

> **Note:** `.css()` ignores `!important` declarations. So, the statement `$( "p" ).css( "color", "red !important" )` does not turn the color of all paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Thanks but its the outer element with the width of 50%

Comment: So if the outer element is 50% then the width of the inner would be 25%

Comment: I've tried to give you the knowledge of the issues in your code... it's your job to convert that knowledge into a solution that works specifically in your case.  I think you'll find that the inner is still 50% of its parent